# Phoenix Gettext error: ** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: 2

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, gettext

In my Phoenix project I have the following translations in my `priv/gettext/pl/error.po` file:

```
msgid "should be at least %{count} character(s)"
msgid_plural "should be at least %{count} character(s)"
msgstr[0] "Ma nieprawidłową długość (powinna wynośić co najmniej %{count})."
msgstr[1] "Ma nieprawidłową długość (powinna wynośić co najmniej %{count})."
```

Now I'm trying to use Gettext in console with following line:

```
Gettext.dngettext(TattooBackend.Web.Gettext, "errors", "should be at least %{count} character(s)", "should be at least %{count} character(s)", 6)
```

This returns me following error:

```
** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: 2
    (tattoo_backend) lib/tattoo_backend/web/gettext.ex:1: TattooBackend.Web.Gettext.lngettext/6
           (gettext) lib/gettext.ex:616: Gettext.dngettext/6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that's caused by the fact that Polish has 3 plural forms, so you need three `msgstr` forms.

For example: jeden stół, dwa stoły, pięć stołów.

Comment: Exactly, Thanks for help.